# Using doxygen with qtcreator

Tags: linux, plugins, qt-creator, doxygen, mageia

I want to use doxygen with qt creator on my linux box with Mageia 3, and I found a qtcreator plugin for this purpose ([here](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/wiki)). Unfortunately this is for qt creator version 2.4 (I use 2.7).
So is there a plugin for 2.7 or is it possible to use doxygen without the plugin in qtcreator? I mean like doxygen tags autocompletion and the like...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the plugin you found: the wiki and binaries are not on par with the source code but it is compatible with qtc 2.7 if you compile it from source. I guess what you want is a binary if you didn't find out yourself.

qtcreator can generate doxygen blocks if you manually start to write the block (activate it in the completion settings of the text editor inside qtcreator settings). However interaction with doxygen binaries is not integrated.

Regards.